# Portable BIT macro in C

Tags: c, arm, portability, arm64

I have a bare metal SW environment that can and compile run on multiple architectures such as `ARM 32-bit v7`/`ARM 64-bit v8` and a custom in-house architecture: let's call it `ARCHX`:

First how different data types are defined on `ARM32`, `ARM64` and `ARCHX`:

(Note: `ARM64` uses `LP64` programming model in this example).

- ARM32/ARM64/ARCHX

  - int: 32/32/16
  - long: 32/64/32
  - pointer: 32/64/16

I've implemented a BIT-macro:

```
#define BIT(n) (0x1U << (n))
```

Now on `ARCHX` if using `BIT` on an int (16-bit in `ARCHX`) this gives an error:

> Warning: shiftcount too large, result is undefined

Now adding `UL` to this macro solves that problem but in general might cause problems on other architectures.

So my question is:

Is this definition of the `BIT` macro not portable between architectures and compilers since I need to use `UL` on some archs, `U` on some and perhaps even `ULL` on some combinations (`ARM64` and `LLP` programming model?).

Perhaps the `BIT` macro should be renamed and divided into `BIT16`, `BIT32` & `BIT64` and be implemented per architecture rather than a generic `BIT`-macro for all architectures?

Comment: Probably you should use some fixed-width types instead of `unsigned` and `unsigned long`

Comment: Is this C or C++?   Two different languages with two different solutions.

Comment: Removed C++ tag

Comment: There is no problem with `1ULL << (n)`. But your question suggests your code has a separate problem: that there are instances where you are storing a 16-bit set of flags (via `unsigned int`) , but then you try to access more than 16 flags within that unit.  To solve this problem you should use fixed-width types for your flag sets, and make sure the `1` in `BIT` is as least as big a type as the largest flag set

Comment: What exactly is the issue with using unsigned long? I can understand a 16-bit architecture not handling >=32-bit values efficiently, much like the long long case on 32-bit machines, but if you need to shift a value beyond the range of an int it's not like you have much of a choice.

Comment: The macro definition will not give this error. You apparently use a bit > 15. Any reason you try to use a bit which apparently does not exist in your architecture? What is that supposed to do? Without a [mcve] it is hard to tell, but from experience, I can say your code is broken.

Comment: @Olaf, I am asking about the portability of my BIT macro and U,UL,ULL. It is not related to any broken code  as it works fine for my ARCHX by using UL in the bit macro when doing 32-bit operations (then there's a discussion if I should use a BIT macro or not but we can take that later... :-)

Comment: @Henrik: The code relies on implementation details which are not guaranteed by the standard, nor by all targeted architectures. So yes, it **is** broken! Note that neither `int` nor `unsigned long` are guaranteed to have 32 bits. The latter is just guaranteed to have a **range** which requires **at least** 32 bits. Note that the problem is not the BIT-macro on ARCHX, but the value of `n` and whatever type your variable is! As I wrote, you should comply to site-rules and provide all required information!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is absolutely no reason to use macros like these to hide away very basic functionality. `x |= 1U << n;` is much clearer than the obscure `x |= BIT(n);`. Always assume that the person reading your code knows the C language, but doesn't know your secret macro language.

So the first thing you should do is to get rid of the macro.

---

That being said, portability is achieved by using the types from `stdint.h`.

```
uint32_t x = (uint32_t)1U << n;
```

is fully portable to any known computer.

Similarly, you could also use the standard `UINTn_C` literal format and type

```
uint32_t x = UINT32_C(1) << n;
```

Comment: `x |= 1 << n` is bugged though.  Correctness > clarity.  IMO `BIT(n)` is clearer than having casts (or UINT32_C) or suffixes littered throughout the code. That's a maintenance nightmare if something needs to change.

Comment: "is fully portable to any known computer." - unless it does not support 32 bit integers. But that would generate a compile-time error, which is acceptable.

Comment: @M.M It is not less bugged than `#define BIT (1 << (n))`. Obviously you shouldn't use signed type literals to perform bit-wise arithmetic (ill edit...). Thats why an explicit cast is excellent practice: it says: "the programmer has given thought to both implicit type promotion and signedness, this code was written by a veteran". Makes the reader relax.

Comment: @Olaf Which known computer did you have in mind when you made that comment?

Comment: @Lundin: I thought about 9/18 bit architectures, but primarily I had some 24 bit DSPs in mind. But as I wrote: if you target architectures which support 32 bit integers, the approach is fine. Focus should be the compiler definitively will catch errors and that's true here.

Comment: @Olaf Anyone grabbing mainstream C code and try to use it on wildly obscure DSPs deserve all the problems they can get. Similarly, anyone spending time making their mainstream C code portable to such systems is wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Lundin: I wouldn't call 24 bit DSPs and the other archs "obscure". After all, the C language has been designed to support a wide variety of archs and 8 bit/byte is not "<insert your prefered divine entity> given". And I don't think OP just grabbed maistream C code, but wrote it himself (or from a co-worker).

Comment: @Olaf The problem is rather that those DSPs in turn were not designed with C in mind. If they had anything at all in their minds when they designed them, it was assembler.

Comment: I agree about that. But it does not change my objection. Why not simply restrict the statement to the archs OP asks for, which apparently **do** support 32 bit integers, thus shall provide `uint32_t`?

Comment: @Lundin I guess we differ,  most of the time when I'm browsing code and see casts everywhere, I do not assume it was written thoughtfully by a veteran!

Comment: @M.M Naive beginner code: `char data; x = data << n;`. This code is has around 3-4 severe bugs. Professional code written by a veteran: `uint8_t data; x = (uint32_t)data << n;` Or pedantically, code with no implicit conversions present at all: `x = (uint8_t)((uint32_t)data << n);`. Although evil-looking, this is how you write robust, portable code.

Comment: Though of course there are naive beginner mistakes caused by casting too, such as the rather classic overflow bug `uint32_t x = (uint32_t)(u16 + u16);`.

Comment: That doesn't imply that any code with a cast is robust and portable

Comment: @Lundin I'm not using "mainstream" C code on the architectures, rather a barebone C test SW. In my opinion, making the C test SW code portable to run on both ARM32/64 and the 16-bit DSP architectures, help me create better, cleaner, decoupled and more portable code. At least for us that aren't able to write _perfectly_ portable code at the first attempt :-)

Comment: @Henrik That shouldn't be an issue if you use the method from this answer. Though in case it is one of those oddball DSPs with 1 byte = 16 bits, then all bets about portability are usually off anyway.

Comment: @Lundin Yep it's an oddball DSP with 16-bit bytes. But besides those major hurdles I've been able to reuse most, if not all, the C code I've initially designed on the ARM architecture. The biggest problem so far would be creating portable correctly packed data structures in the memory to be transferred through some kind of interface, but other than that...

Comment: @Henrik Structures aren't portable. You'd have to disable padding or use serialization/de-serialization routines. But that's another topic entirely.

Comment: @Lundin OK I was using the wrong word: "portable". What I meant was that it's a pain creating a data structure in 16-bit aligned memory. And that's the only part of my code which is kind of ugly and really doesn't work well on other archs than the one I am using.

But in general it's quite exciting using odd-ball archs :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `UINT32_C` macro can be used to make a portable unsigned 32 bit constant.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define BIT(n) (UINT32_C(1) << (n))    
int main(void)
{
    return BIT(10);
}
```

Comment: Will have problem when `n >= 32`

Comment: Trying to portably represent `n>=32` is not possible.  If it is an issue, the macro can range check the argument and throw a build error.  If this is a concern the OP needs `BIT16()`, `BIT32()` type macros as his one target CPU is 16 bit `int` based.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the issue by config define for different platform.
Let's say

```
#ifdef SYSTEM_A
#define BIT_BASE_VALUE 0x1U
#else
#ifdef SYSTEM_B
#define BIT_BASE_VALUE 0x1UL
#endif
#endif

#define BIT(n) (BIT_BASE_VALUE << (n))
```

Comment: Don't use hand-crafted stuff where the standard already provides (better) solutions.